# Is sum of all divisors each multiplied by it's respective totient for a particular number is multiplicative when two numbers are coprime?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, totient-function

Is the formula for nth term of sequence  http://oeis.org/A057660 is multiplicative when the numbers are coprime ? If yes how to prove it? And what is the answer when they are not coprime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function is multiplicative.

First look at the function $g(n)=n\phi(n)$.  This function is multiplicative, using the fact that $\phi$ is multiplicative: For relatively prime $m,n$ we have $g(mn)=mn\phi(mn)=mn\phi(m)\phi(n)=g(m)g(n)$.

But then using the result if a function $f(n)$ is multiplicative, then so is $\sum_{d\mid n} f(d)$ (see for instance https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Sum_Over_Divisors_of_Multiplicative_Function), we get that your function, which is equal to $\sum_{d\mid n} g(d)$, is also multiplicative.

Comment: Thanks but what will be the relation for non coprimes ?

Comment: Well, it won't be multiplicative for non-coprimes.  One can determine the values at prime powers, which then determines the values of the function.

Comment: In number theory, the term *multiplicative function* means by definition only that it is multiplicative on relatively prime inputs. That is because so many standard functions that come up in number theory are multiplicative in this restricted sense ($\varphi(n)$, $\sigma(n)$, $\mu(n)$, and so on). The comparatively few functions that are multiplicative on all pairs of inputs are called *totally multiplicative* for emphasis.