# Modular arithmetic equality

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

> Prove that for every positive integer $n$, $\sum\limits_{d|n}d.\phi
>  (d).\sigma \left(\dfrac{n}{d}\right)=\sum\limits_{d|n}d^2$.

I can prove in the case of $n=p^a$, where $p$ is a prime. I'm stuck at the general case when $n=\prod\limits_{i=\overline{1,k}}p^{a_i}_i$.
Can someone show me how to deal with this case? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's a multiplicative function, no?

Comment: @GerryMyerson so...?

Comment: Well, if you know a multiplicative function for prime powers, you know it for all $n$, right?

Comment: But I don't think $\sum\limits_{d|n}d.\phi (d).\sigma\left(\dfrac{n}{d}\right)$ is multiplicative, though its components are.

Comment: There's a theorem that if $f(n)$ is multiplicative, then so is $\sum_{d\mid n}f(d)$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson do you have the proof for this theorem?

Comment: Every intro Number Theory text ever published has a proof of that theorem. Ten thousand websites have a proof of that theorem. Chances are, even math.stackexchange.com has a proof of that theorem. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/839984/prove-that-sigma-k-is-a-multiplicative-function might help. Or https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1234141/is-sum-of-all-divisors-each-multiplied-by-its-respective-totient-for-a-particul

Comment: Also, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1875521/is-sum-d-n-fd-completely-multiplicative-if-f-is-completely-multiplica

Comment: Making any progress, Alex?